# Poisson distribution - support of the distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-distribution

"Let N be the number of earthquakes occurring somewhere in the world in a 1-year period"

a) I have decided that this fits a poisson distribution. Is this correct? because they haven't given a mean value?

b) what are the set of values this random variable can take? So the support of the distribution of the random variable. Isn't this just 0 - infinity? how do I write this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

See whether the Central Limit Theorem can be used to a good effect. Also, check up the following link: http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~dsmall/stat510-f05/lectures/notes11.doc

Comment: what is the central limit theorem?

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED Please see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: ok thank you. I've read the notes but I still don't understand how I'm meant to figure out the support of the distribution as I haven't been given any values. OR is the question asking for P(X=x) = λ^n-e^-λ/n!